# Undefined function 'sparse' for input arguments of type 'sym'. (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I'm trying to create a sparse matrix that has non-numeric elements.

```
syms a b c;

i = [1 1 2 2];
j = [1 2 1 2];
s = [a b 3 c];

sparse(i,j,s,2,2)
```

which returns this error:

> Undefined function 'sparse' for input arguments of type 'sym'.
>
> Error in Test2 (line 8)
>   sparse(i,j,s,2,2)

Comment: Do you have the Symbolic Math Toolbox?

Comment: Additionally, this is not a sparse matrix. A sparse matrix only makes sense if you have many *zero* elements. You have none.

Comment: There is no such thing as a sparse symbolic matrix in Matlab. You can convert a sparse (numeric) matrix to symbolic but not the other way around.

Comment: Sparse and symbolic very rarely have to be in the same sentence.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, how about the commonly used sentence:  "Although the population is _sparse_, they can all recite the same highly _symbolic_ poem by heart."

Comment: @StewieGriffin you're free to flag my comment if its bluntness offends you;)

Answer (score 3):

As I stated in the comments, there is no such thing as a sparse symbolic matrix in Matlab. This is stated in the documentation for the third input argument for the form of [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html#input_argument_v) you're using:

> **v — Values**
>   scalar | vector | matrix

...

> **Data Types:** double | logical

Matlab's Symbolic Math (and [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ug/use-sparse-and-dense-matrices.html)) may take advantage of inherent sparsity internally (for storage and computation).

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple:  Matlab has no function `sparse()` that takes symbolic variables as arguments. (`s` is your problem)  The only [sparse()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) function takes just numeric elements.

Answer (score 0):

@horchler is correct that more recent versions of Matlab do not support using the `sparse` command on symbolic matrices. However, older versions of Matlab allowed this (I tried `R2011b` and it works there). Thus, you may encounter legacy code that produces the above mentioned error. In this case, you may have to remove the `sparse` commands manually.